# Calculating monthly average in Power Query (M)

Tags: average, powerquery, m

I  need to calculate the monthly average in Power Query based off of historical prices. I created a column key that provides the number of the month (based on the pricing date in the same row), so I can use this to identify locations of the pricing dates that are to be used to calculate the average.

The equivalent in excel would be using averageif...

i.e. =averageif('pricing dates','column key','historical prices')

Appreciate any info or tips on this.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be straightforward Grouping By?

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Input"]}[Content],
    Typed = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Pricing Date", type date}, {"Column key", Int64.Type}, {"Price", type number}}),
    GroupBy = Table.Group(Typed, {"Column key"}, {{"AveragePrice", each List.Average([Price]), type number}})
in
    GroupBy
```